# Не записываются данные в React - state на Mac устройствах

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos

```
  export default class CarBrandSelector extends React.PureComponent<Props , State> {
    /**
     * ParametersComponent constructor.
     *
     * @param props - Component properties
     */
    public constructor(props: Props) {
        super( props );

        this.state = {
            brands: {}
        };
    }

    /**
     * DidMount Checking
     */
    public componentDidMount(): void {
        searchService.getCarList()
            .then( (response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            } )
            .then( (resource: ArrayResourceResponse<Option>) => {
                if((Cookies.get('car_modification') === undefined) || (this.props.car.hasOwnProperty('manufacturer'))) {
                    this.setState({
                        brands: this.indexByAlpha(resource.data),
                    });
                }

            } )
            .catch( (err: Error) => {
                console.error( err.message );
            } );
    }


    /**
     * Rendering all car list
     */
    public renderCarList(): React.ReactNode {
        const brands = Object.keys( this.state.brands );
        if (brands.length === 0) {
            return <p>Список атомобилей пуст.</p>;
        }
        return (
            <div className='carNames'>
                { brands.map( (alpha: string, index: number) => this.renderCarAlpha( alpha , index) ) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Вот запрос возвращает данные, все нормально, ошибка не выводится, но почему-то только на Маках пишет , что переменная `brnads` в которую пишутся данные из `state` пустая , хотя данные приходят . Почему это происходит непонятно и почему только на маках

Comment: может быть в state нет данных потому что проверка `if((Cookies.get('car_modification') === undefined) || (this.props.car.hasOwnProperty('manufacturer')))` возвращает false? например, есть кука

Comment: Но почему это только на маках происходит ?

Comment: И запрос отправляется , и ответ приходит с двухсотым кодом